# Unexpected accident of my board, CH341 issue for Linux or Dead ESP?

Tags: serial, esp8266

I have early midnight accident of my Lolin/Wemos boards. I tried uploads my sketch with a assembly `VIN` to `GND` as my reset button, when i uploads my sketch at more one hundred times, i get my boards cannot be online again or my port cannot readable to my Ubuntu as `/dev/ttyXXX`. usually when i plugged the Usb3.0 cable, the blink led should be turn on at my boards but i didn't get it. How  i can re-flash my boards to be online again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I understanding right, that you shorted Vin to Ground? Have you tried another USB port? Maybe you have blown it's driver.

Comment: @chrisl yap it just as reset button, i tried too but i didn't get my port again, perhaps my driver have blown but when i bought it ,i didn't need to installed the drivers.

Comment: @chrisl do i need a esp8266 firmware flasher to get it back?

Comment: the port has nothing to do with the esp8266. USB is handled by the USB converter chip. You used short circuit as reset?

Comment: I meant the electronic parts inside the USB port of your PC. Sorry for being unaccurate. So you can try another USB port or another PC. Also look at the board, if you can find any parts that look damaged. Currently I cannot investigate further

Comment: Juraj yap!! ,christ i tried to change another usb port and another pc but i didn't get it back

Comment: @chrisl how i can i find any parts that look damaged? perhaps USB converter chip issue but Lolin/Wemos didn't need driver for linux

Comment: Precisely which board do you have?

Comment: @Majenko Lolin/Wemos D1 Mini absolutely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Majenko my pal, from him advice i get a alternative ideas for fixed my issue.

**What i tried :**

1. I found [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=504901.msg3446033#msg3446033) and I took my Uno, i pined 5v (Uno) to 5v (Esp) and i declared 13 pinout as the led blinky and then i uploaded "BlinkyWithoutDelay" sketch, it's seems doesn't work.
2. I pined 5v (Uno) to 5v (Esp), Gnd (Uno) to Gnd (Esp) and i declared 13 pinout (Uno) to D3 pinout (Esp) and then i uploaded "BlinkyWithoutDelay" sketch, it's seems doesn't work.
3. I tried from Majenko advice to provide a Usb phone charger and connected white wire to 5v (Esp) and black wire to Gnd (Esp) without Uno board, and then i uploaded "BlinkyWithoutDelay" sketch, it's seems doesn't work.
4. From the 2nd point and the 3rd point, i run 2nd point without declared D3 pinout as the led blinky, and i changed from 5v to 3v3 (Uno and Esp), and after uploaded the sketch, it's seems the dim light (Esp) works like dim light (Uno) but i still cannot get my port for my esp, i had idea to unplugged my Uno and i changed from 5v to 3v3 and i uploaded my sketch, it's seems works to me. but i still cannot 5v properly or really death.

**The Solution**

From the 4th points , the solution is i provide a external power to 3v3 (esp) and i plugged to Usb2.0, i also plugged Usb3.0 as serial communication. when i uploaded "BlinkyWithoutDelay" sketch, it's seems works. The conclusion is my 5v pinout really death cause the diode for 5v pinout is blown up therefore i changed to 3v3 pinout.

**See my damaged board below**

[image: this]

That's also solved another my Esp boards. hope anyone didn't make a shorted between 5v to Gnd like me.

Thanks.

Comment: this should be an answer?

Comment: @Juraj that's solved my issue, i get my port again, why you provide me down vote man?

Comment: this is not how an answer should be written and I don't understand the solution.

Comment: @Juraj perhaps my bad English man, I editing!!

Comment: leave out the dead ends. write down the working wiring

Comment: @Juraj that's the steps what i did, and the solution really short sentences!!

Comment: @Juraj is my language correct man?

Comment: so you used an external USB-to-TTL-Serial adapter instead of the damaged USB circuit of the NodeMCU. You connected the adapter to Rx,TX,3.3V and ground pins. Without the USB part, the NodeMCU is simply an ESP-12. No USB communication and power and no autoreset for flashing

Comment: @Juraj i'm not used an external USB-to-TTL-Serial adapter and RX TX pins, i just used a external power like Majenko advice , if i use 5v pin i get No USB communication and power and no autoreset for flashing.

Comment: ok, so USB like normal, only 3.3 V external power, because Majenkos's advice to use 5 V pin was wrong since it uses the same damaged circuit as the USB power.

Comment: @Juraj USB abnormal for my damaged boards because my diode for blown up, if i unplugged usb3.0 as serial communication or usb2.0 as external power, i didn't get my port, it requires both. at this morning i buy a new esp and my USB like normally.

Comment: @Juraj hope you can get it man!

Comment: I understand that everything works if you power the board over 3.3V pin

Comment: @Juraj see my little picture man!! why my answer is still considered wrong as down vote?

Comment: @Juraj am i answered section is correct man?

Comment: the picture is poor. and what is that about D3 pin?

Comment: @Juraj no, i didn't used D3 pin as the led blinky, just used "LED_BUILTIN".

Comment: what has that to do with all this?

Comment: @Juraj what's your talking about? ,with my alternative solution, i can get my port again from a external power 3v3 pin instead 5v pin which the diode is blown up

Comment: what has the D3 pin mentioned in you answer to do with the solution?

Comment: @Juraj in 4th point, i didn't used D3 pin as led blinky, but if you used D3 pin as led blinky on "BlinkyWithoutDelay" sketch with a external power and a serial communication, that's same to me

Comment: @Juraj is there anything else wrong man?

Comment: no improvement at all. but I remove the downvote for your effort

Comment: @Juraj thanks, how i can improvement at all?

Comment: @Juraj thanks, what i do to improvement at all?

Answer (score 1):

Shorting VIN to GND will over-stress the diode that is in-line with the power coming in from the USB.

### The result

- The diode will blow and you will not get power from the USB to power the board.
- The PC may detect "over-current" and shut down the USB port
- The USB port on the computer may be damaged

### How do you fix it?

- Replace the diode if blown.
- Use a different USB port.

### How do you work around it?

- Provide an external 5V power source to VIN & GND if the diode is blown

### How do you avoid it happening in future?

- **NEVER short VIN to GND, even for a short time.**  There is a reset pin **RST** provided for the purpose of resetting the board.

Comment: i found it https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=504901.msg3446033#msg3446033 ,do i took another boards and connect 3.3v output to my esp?

Comment: That's a different issue.  Get a USB phone charger, butcher a USB cable, and connect the red wire to VIN and the black wire to GND.  It *may* work.

Comment: okay i trying, do i plug usb3.0 port to esp connector too?

Comment: You will need to for it to communicate with the computer.

Comment: alright i trying

Comment: sorry, it doesn't works sir.

Comment: Then throw it away and get another. They're cheap enough. And don't do it again.

Comment: if the diode is damaged, the 5 V pin will work?

Comment: @Juraj i think you can try connected white jumper wired 5v (uno) to gnd (esp) and black jumper wired gnd (uno) to 5v (esp) then uploaded your sketch. if your saw a brown smoke, your blown out it. and then check your port again. if you cannot get your port, you can try my mine.

Answer (score 0):

If the device still blinks and boots and whatnot, but doesn't connect to the computer, you've probably only broken the USB part of the NodeMCU.

Use the USB-TTL of another MCU. If you have an Uno, it's RST>GND, GND>GND, TX-RX, RX-TX. Mind GPIO 0+15 for programming. You can also use a USB TTL adapter, aka "an FTDI", the kind they used to use before everything had cheap built-in USB chips.

Comment: my device not blinks and cannot detect my port, do i Majenko advice?

Comment: well my suggestion is low-effort and free to try. If I was looking at replacing parts on a NodeMCU, i would just get a new NodeMCU, they are only a few dollars, and fixing it could take hours. If you find the ESP half still working, there's a lot of projects you can still use the board for, especially if you enable OTA updates...

Comment: i try to understanding my issue without a few dollars, and to get work around it, thanks

Comment: how i can enable OTA updates for esp8266?

Comment: this is the simplest method, since it's just an include and one extra line of code on top of an existing server config: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer/examples/WebUpdater/WebUpdater.ino  There's a few other ways to do it as well, through the ardunio IDE and through an external HTTP server, but this one is simple.